# Redux Slice - Actions may not have an undefined "type" property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am currently following Coding Addict's "React Phone E-Commerce Project" and learning to use redux instead of context API. I came across an error:

(Error: Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. You may have misspelled an action type string constant.) after following the docs exactly using slice.

productSlice.js

```
import {createSlice} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import {storeProducts, detailProduct} from '../data';

export const productSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'products',
    initialState: {
        products: storeProducts,
        detailProduct: detailProduct,
    },

    reducers: {
        setProducts: (state, action) => {
            return {...state, products: [...action.payload]}
        },

        handleDetail: (state,action) => {
            return console.log('Hello from productSlice');
        }
    }
});

export const {setProducts, handleDetail} = productSlice.actions;

export default productSlice.reducer;
```

store.js

```
import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import productSlice from './productSlice';

export default configureStore({
    reducer: {
        productSlice: productSlice,
    },
})
```

app.js

```
// CSS
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

// React Stuff
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

// Redux Stuff
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import {handleDetail, setProducts} from './redux/productSlice';

// Components
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar';
import ProductList from './Components/ProductList';
import Details from './Components/Details';
import Cart from './Components/Cart';
import Default from './Components/Default';


function App() {

    const products = useSelector((state) => state.productList.value);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    console.log(products);

    return (
        <Router>
            <Navbar />
            <Routes>
                <Route index path='/' element={<ProductList />} />
                <Route path='/details' element={<Details />} />
                <Route path='/cart' element={<Cart />} />
                <Route path='*' element={<Default />} />
            </Routes>
        </Router>
    );
};

export default App;
```

I know that Redux Reducers need a type value in the payload. I don't see anything in the docs, or other tutorials covering Redux Slice, about types.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The type in Redux Toolkit is an internal implementation detail you do not need to care about. Anything created by a RTK action creator will have a type and can safely be dispatched.

I would assume that you are accidentally dispatching something else somewhere - but you are not sharing any code that calls dispatch at all. For more input, you would have to share move code.

Comment: Yes I have not called dispatch anywhere. Would that cause the error? I just wanted to test and make sure that setting the initial state was working.

Comment: You are definitely dispatching something somewhere, otherwise you could not get this error message. Search your code base for any kind of dispatch. The error should even give you a stack trace with the exact line triggering it.

Comment: Thank you, that was it. I had an empty dispatch in index.js